# asp.net mvc with jqgrid and orderby

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm stuck on what to do with OrderBy. This is the code in their example:

```
    public ActionResult DynamicGridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {
        var repository = new ItemRepository();
        int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
        int pageSize = rows;
        int totalRecords = repository.GetItemQuery().Count();
        var totalPages = (int) Math.Ceiling(totalRecords/(float) pageSize);

        IQueryable<Item> items = repository.GetItemQuery()
            .OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord) // <-- problem is here.
            .Skip(pageIndex*pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize);

        var jsonData = new
                        {
                            total = totalPages,
                            page,
                            records = totalRecords,
                            rows = (from item in items
                                    select new
                                            {
                                                i = item.Id,
                                                cell = new[]
                                                        {
                                                            item.Id.ToString(), item.Description
                                                        }
                                            }).ToArray()
                        };
        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In my code, the model looks like this:

```
public class Person{
    public int PersonId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

How do I set this up in my orderby method?

ps. in their code, I see 2 calls. a `Count` and getting the paged stuff. Is this 2 database calls or one?

Comment: what are you trying to do with the order by clause??

Comment: @JQiro, apparently, the grid sends a `sidx` and `sord` param. They put that in the OrderBy. If I do it, it throws an error about ambigous thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

The `OrderBy` method expects an expression and not string which is what you are trying to pass. You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://landman-code.blogspot.com/2008/11/linq-to-entities-string-based-dynamic.html) which illustrates an `OrderBy` extension method method which can take a string parameter.

Comment: So this example is using dynamic linq?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of code I'm using to handle OrderBy situations:

```
public ActionResult GetAvailableChapters(string sidx, string sord, string userName)
{
    ...
    IEnumerable<ChapterViewModel> viewModel = _repository.GetChapters();

    switch (sidx)
    {
        case "Chapter_Name":
            viewModel = sord == "desc"
                ? viewModel.OrderByDescending(ch => ch.Name)
                : viewModel.OrderBy(ch => ch.Name);
            break;
        default:
            viewModel = sord == "desc"
                ? viewModel.OrderByDescending(ch => ch.Number)
                : viewModel.OrderBy(ch => ch.Number);
            break;
    }

    ...

    return ...
}
```

Comment: I agree with this. the `sord` string is merely jqgrid telling you in which order it wants the records. It's up to your code to interpret that string accordingly.

Comment: This method works great when your Grid includes column from related tables. ex. Your Orders grid contains the Customer name order.Customer.Name. using PropertyInfo becomes a problem since the entity order does not have this property. Instead having a case statement like this comes in very hand.

Answer (score 0):

This method will do 2 database calls.
Actually to use Take~Skip extensions methods with entity framework, is required to use OrderBy before. The action *DynamicGridData* will be fired automatically to retrieve the data(sorting as well), even you don't sort anything, you need to sort a default property(like ID). I don't remember if jqGrid has a DefaultSortField(sorry).
If you're starting to use jqGrid I highly recommend you to use [this free library](http://www.playground.webpirates.nl/MvcJqGrid/) to accomplish yours goals with jqGrid. It's very easy to use and I think that will help you with ur problem.